# What layout constraint is this talking about?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've read all the SO questions that are similar to this and I'm so lost.  I'm getting the following error:

```
2015-09-14 22:59:40.455 guess-who[60143:9602686] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c0f8e30 UIImageView:0x7b6efb60.top == _UILayoutGuide:0x7c0f67a0.top>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7c0f8ae0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7c0f67a0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7c0f0070 _UILayoutGuide:0x7c0f67a0.bottom == UIView:0x7c0f65e0.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b6f6130 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x7b6efb60.midY == + 204>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b6f6160 h=--& v=--& V:[UIImageView:0x7b6efb60(220)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b6f6dc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7c0f65e0(518)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b6f6e20 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7c0f65e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7c0effc0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7c0f0070 _UILayoutGuide:0x7c0f67a0.bottom == UIView:0x7c0f65e0.bottom>
```

I've gotten this for a bunch of other constraints which I've successfully solved, but this one is stumping me.  I don't know what a `UILayoutSupportConstraint` is; the documentation is not very thorough.  I've looked through the view debugger and `UIView:0x7c0f65e0` seems to refer to my main view (although it's the child of a blank view, for some reason?).  I'm not able to find anything with 0x7c0f67a0, although that seems to refer to the LayoutGuide, saying their bottoms must be equal.  I'm not sure what other tools are available for me to use to figure this out.

EDIT:

Using the View Debugger, I've narrowed it down to one of these two constraints, neither of which I know the source of:

[image]

I can't find where either of these gets set.  I know everyone's first suggestion is to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, but that destroys my entire layout and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like either the view or the image view is over-constrained vertically.  You have set a height as well as top and bottom space constraints

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Done

Comment: Where is the github repo?

Comment: @matt https://github.com/pnichols104/guess_who

Comment: Have you noticed that in the storyboard, your buttons PlayAgain, FirstChoice, and so on, aren't even on the screen? Surely that should get you thinking that something is wrong here.

Comment: @matt Yes; when I hit "update frames" it made it look like that.  I wasn't able to figure out how to fix it, but it still ran without a problem

Answer (score 9):

You could also consider adding accessibility identifiers and constraint identifiers to your views to make your AL logs more legible:

`constraintVariableName.identifier = “constraintVariableName”;`

In InterfaceBuilder, use the identifier property in the inspector.

`self.loginButton.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("LoginButtonAccessibilityLabel", @"");`

These id's will end up in the logs, such as you posted above, replacing things like UIView, UIImageView and UIConstraint with the ids.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have given constraints to image view with relation to Superview. So to satisfy you constraint of UILayoutGuide.bottom your constraints are broken. As you have **added more or unnecessary constraints** which were not required.

**Constraints which are getting broken are**:

1. UILayoutGuide.top = UIView.top
2. UILayoutGuide.height = 0
3. UILayoutGuide.bottom = UIView.bottom
4. UIImageView Height constraint
5. UIImageView Y position
6. UIView Height constraint
7. You have given UIView vertical spacing from top is '0' but missing bottom/height constraint.

Try changing the **priority of height constraints** from **1000 to 750** for UIImageview with height(220),UIView with height(518).

Also you need to check for bottom constraint for 
`"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b6f6e20 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7c0f65e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7c0effc0 )>"`

If it is possible then please attach demo on git for better idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is helpful, but I can't see _where_ constraints 3 and 4 might have been assigned, or how to find them to change their priority.  I do some work with constraints in my ViewController, but I don't see anything that relates.  (plus I get the error when they're commented out anyway)

Comment: @thumbtackthief - First of all you need to select the view. Let’s consider of you 4th constraint of UIImageView Height. All you need to do is to select your UIImageView and go to Utilities panel on right hand side of xCode and select Show Size Inspector. There you will find constraint you have given to your view. Double tap on the constraint you want to change it’s priority.

Comment: @thumbtackthief - Secondly for bottom layout guide you need to check for all bottom layout guide. It will be a Straight Horizontal Line or you can select select it from Document Outline panel in which you have already selected 2 constraints. Select one Constraint and you can see it constant value, Priority and multiplier in Size Inspector.

Comment: @thumbtackthief - If possible please attach demo so I'll be able to help you out if still problem persists. Otherwise you can add screenshot of how your view will appear and how you require it.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't know what you mean by 'attach a demo' (I mean, I know what those words mean, but not sure exactly what I need to do.)  For the record, this runs fine both on my simulator and on my phone--it just gives me the error message in the logs.

Comment: Also, the constraints I highlighted in the question were in the iew Debugger.  I'm unable to find them in the Document Outline panel.  When I click Bottom Layout Guide there, the Size Inspector just says "Not Applicable".

Answer (score 2):

Disabling translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints wrecks your layout because some of your stacked elements have no explicit height/width set (PlayAgain, cat, frame) and are based off the image contents.

Your example project isn't runnable out of the box, so I can't inspect the runtime layout. However, I'd start by specifying the height of those elements so there are fewer auto constraints. It also looks like you're changing a lot of the constraints at runtime, so you need to be cautious about altering constraints that will conflict with each other. Make sure that the layout's happy before you start constraint-constant fiddling!

Answer (score -3):

Use this following Line. It may be help you.

```
[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: I've tried this (well, the Swift equivalent) and it totally messes up my entire layout.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it should be a comment.

Comment: Plus it doesn't help, and is in Obj-C.

Comment: In Swift, that code is `view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`